HADOOP ERROR: STARTING NAMENODE Cannot set priority of namenode process
I am currently facing this issue.
(base) annguyen@annguyen-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-5:~/hadoop-3.4.0$ start-dfs.sh Starting namenodes on [annguyen-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-5] annguyen-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-5: ERROR: Cannot set priority of namenode process 26930 

here is my configuration file
hdfs-site.xml
<configuration>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>1</value>
 </property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>/data/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>/data/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>

core-site.xml
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://NAMENODE_SERVER_FQDN:9000</value>
</property>
 <property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.dataflair.groups</name> <value>*</value>
 </property>
 <property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.dataflair.hosts</name> <value>*</value>
 </property>
 <property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.server.hosts</name> <value>*</value>
 </property>
 <property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.server.groups</name> <value>*</value>
 </property>
</configuration>

Could you please help me to fix this issue. Thank you.
I try to start-all.sh and face this error. I am using Hadoop 3.4.0.
